# Set default argument(function type) on template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a template function, with several std::function type arguments, I want to default one of these arguments, such that the other programs calling it will not need to specify that input arguments. For example:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
dataStruct<T1, T2> foo(std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_1, 
                       std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_2,
                       std::function<double(T1, T1)> param_3) {...}
```

I want to set `param_3` to have a default value of `1.0`, so if I want to call this template function, I only need call it like this:

```
dataStruct<int, int> solution = foo(input_fun1, input_fun2);
```

such that I don't need to specify `param_3` if its value is just default `1.0`.
I know I can overload it with less parameters, but any way to skip this overload? like set default value in this template function directly?
`std::function<double(T1, T1)> param_3 = setToOne()` something like this?

Comment: You could set the default value of `param_3` to a static function that will take your parameters and always return `1.0`, but depending on your implementation, it would probably end up being less readable than the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a lambda as a default parameter:

```
template<class T1, class T2>
dataStruct<T1, T2> foo(std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_1,
                       std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_2,
                       std::function<double(T1, T1)> param_3 = [](T1, T1) { return 1.0; })
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Extrapolated to the OP's code:

`template<class T1, class T2>
dataStruct<T1, T2> foo(
    std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_1,
    std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_2,
    std::function<double(T1, T1)> param_3 = [](T1, T1) { return 1.0; })
{ ... }`

Comment: You're right, I should have done that in the first place.  Edited into the answer.

Comment: Using lambda, I still need to specify this param_3 when call `foo()`, right? I tried on my complier and return no match function error.

Comment: @EmersonXu: Your `param_N` may be a function pointer (e.g. `T2 (*)(T1, T1)` and not a `std::function<T2(T1, T1)>`, so you need to help the compiler figure out which instantiation of `foo` you want to call.  One way to do this is to explicitly specify the template arguments `T1` and `T2` when calling `foo`: e.g. `foo<int, std::string>(p1, p2)`.  Another way is to convert your function pointers to `std::function` before calling `foo`: e.g. `std::function<int, std::string> f1 = p1;`, and then pass `f1` et al. to `foo` instead of `p1` et al.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to set `param_3` to have a default value of `1.0`.

I don't think you can do that. The value of a `std::function<double(T1, T1)>` cannot be `1.0`. One option is to overload the function.

```
template <class T1, class T2>
dataStruct<T1, T2> foo(std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_1, 
                       std::function<T2(T1, T1)> param_2,
                       double param_3 = 1.0) { ... }
```

Comment: There are plenty of ways you can achieve this, e.g. [this somewhat silly idea](http://ideone.com/wNxWbC) or as the other answer points out, a lambda.